# How do I use a generator expression or list comprehension to generate a series of numbers starting with 000?

Tags: list, scrapy, generator

I'm crawling and the pages I'm dealing with have sequential page IDs.
There is no link such as 'Next Page' for the crawler to follow.

So, I want to produce a list of numbers starting with

00000001

and ending with

00013099

But am having trouble writing an expression/comprehension which captures that. Will be very grateful for any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy's `response.follow(href, callback)` works not only with actual hrefs to be scraped from the page, but also with auto-generated ones... simply use a for cicle, then generate links by string concatenation, and pass it to follow.

Comment: thank you! the thing is with concatenation, I have to keep track of the number of zeros to concatenate?

Comment: you can use a for cycle to concatenate as much zeroes as you need, then save it to a string and add it to final href.